# how to send random get request to the API endpoint using request and time modules in python

Tags: python, django, automation, request

how to send random get request to the API endpoint  using request  and time modules in python

Answer (score 0):

if you want just an example of how to do a request, here's a get request of a list of product from an api.

```
# import the Requests library 
import requests
# define the base URL for the API 
base_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/' 
# random example of a get a list of products,(put your specific endpoint)
r = requests.get(f'{base_url}products/')
# json() method of the response object to decode the JSON data returned by the API
products = r.json()
products_list = ', '.join([product['name'] for product in products])
# print products names
print(f'Available products: {products_list}')
```

or you could use "products" as a context in a fuction or class